# Wii extended range sensor bar

Tags: nintendo-wii

My gaming room is just a bit too big. At the far end, where most of my couch space is, the Wii is on the limit of it's detection range, skipping from one frame to the next. I have heard there are devices on the market that can extend the range of the Wii sensors somewhat, but a search on Amazon has lead me to a million entries, impossible to tell one from the next. I should say, I don't want a wireless solution, I just as soon would keep my batteries, thank you very much.

So, two questions

1. Do these special bars actually work?
2. What is the best way to actually find one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea to try before buying anything is to increase the sensitivity of the wii remote. [EHow covers this nicely](http://www.ehow.com/how_5959290_increase-range-wii-sensor.html), here's the general steps.

1. Start the Wii, press the Wii button in the lower left, and choose Wii Settings. Then find the sensor bar option. This is tucked in deep, so...
2. Sit in the area where you are having difficulty.
3. Increase the sensitivity until you see two blinking white dots. This can be done by pressing the + button on the wii remote.

Stop increasing it once you see both dots blinking. This should minimize the chance of the wii remote using an invalid target.

Also, ensure that no warm devices (Sunlight, Christmas lights, etc), are near the TV.

Answer (score 7):

The Wii's sensor bar isn't really a sensor, per se.  It's a pair of infrared LEDs mounted some distance apart.  Since it's so simple, it's easily duplicated.  I've heard of people even just putting lit candles on either side of their TV, which put off a considerable amount of infrared, although fire and electronics don't seem like a good mix to me.

I'd say look for something inexpensive, but from a brand you're familiar with when it comes to console accessories.  Nyko and Madcatz are both common brands in this space.  I'd also make sure you order it from someplace reputable that is willing to let you return it or give you your money back if you purchased a dud.

Batteries aren't actually that bad in one of these, since they're essentially moderately low power infrared LED flashlights.  The batteries should last a pretty long time in such a low-powered device.

Comment: I just wanted to add that the candle idea works wonderfully, there almost seems to be limitless range on them as well so they may be worth checking out.